# Update Excel 2010 But No Row Changes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, oledb, excel-2010

I want to use OLEDB to update Excel 2010 file with these code as below.

I find when I debug this code, there is no exception but the excel file column(Status) content is not updated, someone who can help?

P.S. The sql statement is like this:

`UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Status ='Imported' WHERE Status IN ( SELECT TOP 5 Status FROM [Sheet1$])`.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(GetExcelConnectionStringByWrite(filePath));
MyConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
//sql.Append("UPDATE [");
//sql.Append(sheetName);
//sql.Append("S1:S");
//sql.Append(rowNum);
//sql.Append("] SET Status ='Imported'");

//---------New Update SQL---------
sql.Append("UPDATE [");
sql.Append(sheetName);
sql.Append("] SET Status ='Imported' WHERE Status IN ( SELECT TOP ");
sql.Append(rowNum);
sql.Append(" Status FROM ");
sql.Append("[");
sql.Append(sheetName);
sql.Append("])");

//------------End-----------------


myCommand.CommandText = sql.ToString();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MyConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the exact same code but with minor modifications as follows and it has operated as desired.

Before:

```
 COLUMN A has fieldname called Status
 A1 Status
 A2 A
 A3 B
 A4 C
 A5 D
 A6 E
 A7 F
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace StackoverflowExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            using(var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(GetExcelConnectionStringByWrite()))
            using (var myCommand = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                myCommand.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Status ='Imported' WHERE Status IN ( SELECT TOP 5 Status FROM [Sheet1$] )";
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string GetExcelConnectionStringByWrite()
        {
            return
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\cys\desktop\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;MAXSCANROWS=10;READONLY=FALSE'";
        }

    }
}
```

After:

```
 COLUMN A has fieldname called Status
 A1 Status
 A2 Imported
 A3 Imported
 A4 Imported
 A5 Imported
 A6 Imported
 A7 F
```

Comment: Thanks zfus,I think maybe my OLEDB driver is not correct,My OS is Win7 64 bit,and Office 2010 is 32 bit.so the OLEDB driver is 32 bit!

Comment: I ran the above code successfully on 64bit Win 7 + 32bit office. What happens when you try the above code with a new, simple XLSX file?

Comment: @Michael I have uploaded the a solution to https://github.com/zedfoxus/Presentations. Go ahead and download [StackOverflow18627032.zip](https://github.com/zedfoxus/Presentations/blob/master/StackOverflow18627032.zip) and click on Raw. Unzip, open the project and run the application. Test.xlsx is in the bin/debug and bin/release directory. Check if the project runs well for you.

Comment: Hi zfus,Thanks for your sharing.Your code didn't throw exception as same as what I wrote before,unfortunately, the test.xlsx file cann't be updated as "Imported" on my laptop.and I don't know why.

Comment: Hi @Michael, are you opening test.xlsx that sits under StackOverflow18627032/bin/Debug directory? If so, open it in Excel and change some information in the cells, save it and try again. I am getting curious why the updates don't work just on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

knowing how difficult it could be to find a solution to such mysterious issues I recommend you to post an extract of your excel file. Furthermore I need to know what happens in GetExcelConnectionStringByWrite(filePath).

Because those items are abscent I can only give two common reasons:

- the HDR section in your connection string is not set to 'YES' and your provider doesn't know any header names
- the provider will check for the columns data type within the first eight rows -> does your sheet provide enough data values in those eight rows?

Regards
Jan

Comment: Hi Jan,the fucntion GetExcelConnectionStringByWrite(filePath) will return a string: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\\\Michael\\\\Project1\\\\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;MAXSCANROWS=10;READONLY=FALSE\" and the Test.xlsx has title and more than 1000 rows.

Comment: I have tested the sql "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Status ='Imported' " it works.It seems OLEDB for Excel doesn't support "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET Status ='Imported' WHERE Status IN ( SELECT TOP 5 Status FROM [Sheet1$])"SQL Statement.

Comment: Seems like Excel isn't Oracle :-)